# How can I block copy-paste in a text field?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin22

I'm using vaadin 22 and I want to block the copy-paste of an emailField to implement email confirmation.
Can someone help me.
Thank you

Comment: Olivers example works great for EmailField just like TextField. However I would recommend to add his solution to both fields. Suppose the user types wrong e-mail in first field but correct in second. Without "anti-copy" on both fields the user may copy the correct value from field2 into field1. I would probably even extend EmailField and add Olivers solution and just use that new field for an even cleaner solution.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice, I will apply it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. We'd like to know what you tried to solve this. Without that we have to write a tutorial or give you generalized answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML you want to archive something like this:

```html
 <input type="textbox" onpaste="return false;" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false">
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/f4g6opcm/1/

So you can simply add this Attributes via Vaadin like this:

```java
TextField textfield = new Textfield();
textfield.getElement().setAttribute("onpaste", "return false");
textfield.getElement().setAttribute("oncopy", "return false");
textfield.getElement().setAttribute("oncut", "return false");
textfield.getElement().setAttribute("ondrag", "return false");
textfield.getElement().setAttribute("ondrop", "return false");
```

Comment: Thank you, it has solved my problem, I am very grateful.